# cudaMemcpyToSymbol fails when constant is not an array

Tags: cuda

CUDA constant memory in all posted code examples seem to be arrays, yet I could not find this as a requirement in the documentation.  So why does cudaMemcpyToSymbol in the following fail with cudaErrorInvalidSymbol:

```
    __constant__ int dev;

int main()
{
    int host = 2;
    cudaError_t error = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(&dev, &host, sizeof(host));
    printf(cudaGetErrorString(error));
}
```

while the following succeeds?

```
    __constant__ int dev[1];

int main()
{
    int host = 2;
    cudaError_t error = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev, &host, sizeof(host));
    printf(cudaGetErrorString(error));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A device symbol is not like an ordinary host-code C variable or address.  You use the symbol name whether it is an "ordinary" device variable or an array.

Do this instead:

```
    __constant__ int dev;

int main()
{
    int host = 2;
    cudaError_t error = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev, &host, sizeof(host));
    printf(cudaGetErrorString(error));
}
```

All I did was remove the ampersand in front of `dev`

Comment: I find it a little confusing because the documentation marks the first parameter to the function as `const void*` I was doing the same until I found this post. Could you elaborate more on why the name of a constant variable in cuda refers to its address?

Comment: Not sure I can elaborate a lot.  A device **symbol** is not the same as an ordinary host address that is addressable in host code.  First of all, it is a device location, and secondly it is referenced under the hood via a symbol-table lookup rather than an ordinary C/C++ pointer addressing mechanism.  The `cudaMemcpy...Symbol` functions perform this device symbol table lookup, and then discover the device address at runtime.  Taking the address (`&`) of a device symbol is not sensible in this context.